# FMOD CreateSound with a user-created stream

Tags: c#, fmod

Given a DLL that's supposed to play SNES SPC files and FMOD, in C#, why does this call to `system.createSound` fail?

```
var ret = system.init(32, FMOD.INITFLAGS.NORMAL, (IntPtr)null);
var soundEx = new FMOD.CREATESOUNDEXINFO()
{
    cbsize = Marshal.SizeOf(soundEx),
    fileoffset = 0,
    length = ~0U,
    numchannels = 2,
    defaultfrequency = 32000,
    format = FMOD.SOUND_FORMAT.PCM16,
    pcmreadcallback = pcmreadcallback,
    pcmsetposcallback = pcmsetposcallback,
    dlsname = null,
};
var mode = FMOD.MODE.DEFAULT | FMOD.MODE.OPENUSER
         | FMOD.MODE.LOOP_NORMAL | FMOD.MODE.CREATESTREAM;
ret = system.createSound((string)null, mode, ref soundEx, ref sound);
//^-- ERR_INVALID_PARAM
ret = system.playSound(FMOD.CHANNELINDEX.FREE, sound, false, ref channel);
```

Compare that with the `usercreatedsound` sample that comes with FMOD:

```
FMOD.MODE mode = (FMOD.MODE._2D | FMOD.MODE.DEFAULT
               | FMOD.MODE.OPENUSER | FMOD.MODE.LOOP_NORMAL
               | FMOD.MODE.HARDWARE);
//snip
createsoundexinfo.cbsize            = Marshal.SizeOf(createsoundexinfo);
createsoundexinfo.fileoffset        = 0;
createsoundexinfo.length            = frequency * channels * 2 * 2;
createsoundexinfo.numchannels       = (int)channels;
createsoundexinfo.defaultfrequency  = (int)frequency;
createsoundexinfo.format            = FMOD.SOUND_FORMAT.PCM16;
createsoundexinfo.pcmreadcallback   = pcmreadcallback;
createsoundexinfo.pcmsetposcallback = pcmsetposcallback;
createsoundexinfo.dlsname           = null;
//snop
result = system.createSound(
    (string)null, 
    (mode | FMOD.MODE.CREATESTREAM), 
    ref createsoundexinfo,
    ref sound);
```

Length, frequency... doesn't matter.

Edit: I've already confirmed that the SPC player works, at least as far as initialization goes, and the sample that came with FMOD builds and runs just fine. *The only particularly meaningful change, aside from twiddling the settings in an attempt to get it to run, is writing it in 4.0 style.*

Answer (score 1):

Playback of an arbitrary sample rate is not necessarily available on all sound cards. 32Khz is not a 'common' rate such 44.1, 48, 96 etc ...

- Did you try FMOD.MODE.SOFTWARE ?
- You might be able to use an arbitrate sample rate using [ASIO4ALL](http://www.asio4all.com/) but you'll need to switch to ASIO.

Are you tied to FMOD ? If not, then consider [BASS.NET](http://www.un4seen.com/), you'll have much more control than in FMOD for doing such stuff.

Example for using BASSMix :
see remarks below

```
using System;
using Un4seen.Bass;
using Un4seen.Bass.AddOn.Mix;

namespace XXX
{
    public class Resampler : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly int _channels;
        private readonly string _filename;
        private readonly int _samplerate;

        public Resampler(string filename, int samplerate, int channels)
        {
            if (filename == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("filename");
            if (samplerate <= 0) throw new ArgumentNullException("samplerate");
            if (channels <= 0) throw new ArgumentNullException("channels");

            #region Initialize BASS stuff

            #endregion

            _filename = filename;
            _samplerate = samplerate;
            _channels = channels;
        }

        #region IDisposable Members

        public void Dispose()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion

        public void Resample(string filename)
        {
            if (filename == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("filename");
            Exceptions.ThrowIfPathInvalid(filename);

            #region Create stream and mixer

            int channel = Bass.BASS_StreamCreateFile(filename, 0, 0,
                                                     BASSFlag.BASS_STREAM_PRESCAN | BASSFlag.BASS_STREAM_DECODE |
                                                     BASSFlag.BASS_SAMPLE_FLOAT);
            if (channel == 0)
                throw new BassException("Couldn't create stream.");

            var mixer = BassMix.BASS_Mixer_StreamCreate(22050, 1, BASSFlag.BASS_STREAM_DECODE | BASSFlag.BASS_SAMPLE_FLOAT);
            if (mixer == 0)
                throw new BassException("Couldn't create mixer stream.");

            if (!BassMix.BASS_Mixer_StreamAddChannel(mixer, channel,
                                                     BASSFlag.BASS_MIXER_DOWNMIX | BASSFlag.BASS_MIXER_FILTER |
                                                     BASSFlag.BASS_MIXER_NORAMPIN))
                throw new BassException("Couldn't add stream channel to mixer.");

            #endregion

            int sr = 22050;
            int secs = 20;
            int samples0 = sr * secs;
            var buffer = new float[samples0];
            int length = sizeof(float) * buffer.Length;
            var getData = Bass.BASS_ChannelGetData(mixer, buffer, length | (int)BASSData.BASS_DATA_FLOAT);
            if (getData != length)
            {
                throw new BassException("");
            }
            var bassMixerChannelRemove = BassMix.BASS_Mixer_ChannelRemove(channel);
            var streamFree = Bass.BASS_StreamFree(channel);
            var bassStreamFree = Bass.BASS_StreamFree(mixer);
        }
    }
}
```

(works in VS2010 with latest bass)

Some extra hints:

- You must call BASS.Bass_Init first,
- Do not forget to copy bass.dll and bassmix.dll next to your EXE,
- I personally would stick to BASS_SAMPLE_FLOAT even though your source is not, the biggest benefit is that you won't get clipping with this format, I'm telling you this because I made an audio wrapper for a NES emu which APU's output was quite 'dynamic', it proven to be helpful. Also that keeps things simpler and of the best quality possible.
- In your case you'd want to use a push stream and feed it with your SNES output : Bass..::..BASS_StreamCreatePush
- Create a 'standard' mixer stream (not a decoding one), plug your push stream, play the mixer
- In the example it is a decoding stream because I needed to process data, not play it back.
- The BassException is just something I created myself, change it to whatever you want
- Your best friend will be the CHM help file but also their forum.
- I suggest you start something with this code then post your new code should you have any problems.

I have to say that BASS is quite hard to grasp at first, but very rewarding in the end. I had the exact same feeling recently when learning OpenGL 3.X; it was incomprehensible at first but now I can do a lot of things. I would say that BASS is on par with OpenGL as it is with 3D.

Sorry but I got quite sick since last time, haven't used the PC mostly, but I seen your message and wanted to respond quickly so you can move on. Should someone complain from SO about the layout of my answer : I will fix it later.

Comment: Software mode and/or 44.1Khz didn't change a thing. Gonna look into BASS.NET for a bit now...

Comment: Basically you'll need BassMix addon, you create a 44.1Khz mixer and then you add your 32Khz source to it; finally you play that mixer. If you need help about it, just ask.

Comment: No I meant as in BASS doesn't work. It breaks on the samples' first call to Bass.BASS_Init().

Comment: For this my 2nd hint, plus you have GetError to know what really happened. Also, if you are on 64-bit : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863197/unable-to-capture-unhandled-exceptions-in-winforms/10863328#10863328