# Visual Studio not breaking on user-unhandled exceptions

Tags: debugging, exception, visual-studio-2012, ide

When running my app in Visual Studio, it's ending on unhandled exceptions rather than showing a message box with the exception info and continuing on as I'm accustomed to.

What options do I need to change to get it back to the behavior I'm used to?

Edit:  In Debug/Exceptions I do have the User-unhandled option selected for CLR Exceptions.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`Debug->Exceptions->Check Thrown/User-Unhandled` for Common Language Runtime Exceptions

edit: Maybe try to do a clean/rebuild, and run again? Maybe debug symbols are corrupt or something..

Comment: I'm looking under Debug/Options and Settings/Debugging/General, but I don't see that option.  Am I looking in the right place?

Comment: @Brandon oops sorry, typo. It's under debug->exceptions

Comment: Found it: It's under Debug/Exceptions, not Debug/Options

Comment: Ok, still not working quite right. :/  I already had User-Unhandled checked but it's not breaking (it's just ending).  And I don't want 'Thrown' checked because then it breaks even if I am already handling the exception.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @Brandon did you drill down into User-Unhandled to see that all of the underlying exception types were also checked? You could have the top level checked while many underlying ones are unchecked.

Comment: It's a clear check (not greyed).  I just double checked to make sure though and they're all checked.  I feel like I ran into this problem once before several months ago but I can't remember if I actually fixed it or if it was just some fluke behavior in VS.

Comment: @Brandon perhaps a clean/rebuild is worth a shot?

Comment: Thanks for the help Tom.  That didn't work either, but I started a new project to see if debugging would throw on exceptions properly and it did so I think I'm just gonna try to create a new project and copy stuff over to it when I get a chance and see what happens.

Comment: @Tom Studee: Thank you! Never thought to look there, my VS' settings somehow reset themselves, wasn't breaking anymore, very difficult to debug.

Comment: Since VS 2015: Debug > Windows > [Exception Settings](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/02/23/the-new-exception-settings-window-in-visual-studio-2015/) or `Ctrl+Alt+E`

Comment: in VS 2015 there is no such checkbox there ?

Comment: I accidentally turned this off in a stupid popup window and now I can't find how to re-enable it. This checkbox does not exist in VS 2019.

Answer (score 59):

For visual studio 2015 :

1.Open Exception settings window (it's new in 2015)
[image: open Exception settings window (it's new in 2015)]

2.Check All CLR Exceptions
[image]

3.If you don't need visual studio to throw specific exceptions uncheck this
[image]

Comment: I opened the Exception window and hit 'Reset to Defaults' and this resolved my issues in VS2017

Comment: Finally I can add proper exception handling to python, thanks!

Answer (score 27):

Depending on the application, the following options may help you:

Tools → Options... → Debugging → General

- Break when exceptions cross AppDomain or managed/native boundaries (Managed only)
- Enable the exception assistant

  - Unwind the call stack on unhandled exceptions

[**Note:** Based on comments below, the following tip did not work and, for some, created the problem answer was intended to solve: use with caution...]

- ***Uncheck*** Enable Just My Code ← JMC can prevent you from catching exceptions in code that's not yours and/or is missing symbols.

Comment: Thanks, I was really hoping unchecking Just My Code would do it but none of the above worked.  I just started a new project to see if I got the same behavior when an error was thrown, but it worked correctly even though (I think) the settings should be the same.  Next step is copying stuff into a new project I guess.

Comment: **Disabling** *Enable Just My Code* caused Visual Studio to hide the *User-unhandled* column in the *Exceptions* window, and it prevented Visual Studio from breaking on *any* user-unhandled exceptions. So in my case, your instructions actually cause the problem this question is trying to solve!

Comment: `Break when exceptions cross AppDomain or managed/native boundaries (Managed only)` worked for me. My DLL was being loaded dynamically through reflection. In this case, Visual Studio debugger was not breaking even when an unhandled exception was getting raised in user code.

Answer (score 23):

In my case, when I went to *Debug* -> *Exceptions*, the *User-unhandled* column was missing. Going to *Debug* -> *Options and Settings* and enabling *Enable Just My Code* fixed this, which consequently fixed this problem altogether.

Answer (score 4):

This fixed it for me: in the quick lauch (Ctrl-Q) type "ResetToC#" (or ResetTo something else)

I had the same problem for a long time. In the Debug->Exceptions menu, the "User-unhandled" column was missing! Extremely annoying.

I uninstalled all my plugins, did a reinstall of VS, but nothing worked (Visual Studio probably left some settings on my machine that it reused after reinstalling).

This might not seem like the best solution as there must be some setting somewhere that would have done it as well. I couldn't find it and after not being able to break on user-unhandled exceptions for months, the ResetToC# option was a relief.

Comment: Thanks, if I run into this issue again I'll definitely try this since nothing else seemed to work :)

Comment: In my case, the reason the *User-unhandled* column was missing was *Enable Just My Code* was disabled in the Debugging options.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue in Visual Studio 2013 on a very large C# project. However if I created a new empty project and threw a test ApplicationException, everything would work as expected and the debugger would break and give me the exception assistant. Doing the same on my existing project would just stop debugging and return to VS editing mode. I noticed in the "Output" window, the last debug trace would show

> The program '[2624] MyApplication.vshost.exe' has exited with code
>   -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

I don't really have the luxury of copying everything into a new project, and none of the suggestions above worked for me. By trial and error I found something that worked: **Uncheck the "Unwind the call stack on unhandled exceptions" under Options > Debugging > General > Enable the exception assistant**.

By the way, if I manually force the call stack to unwind on this same C# project through the exception assistant (by clicking the "Enable editing" link), the debugger just closes and I can't edit-and-continue. But on a fresh project, it does unwind and edit-and-continue works just fine! So there is a definitely something about my project that VS does not like, but I'll use this as an acceptable workaround for now.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing that worked for me was:

Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset all settings and then reset to C#.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017, it's Tools -> Environment - > Import and Export Settings... And my Visual Studio 2017 has no option to reset to C# (or any other language for that matter)...

Answer (score 2):

Changing target platform from x64 to x86 helped me

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one Web Site project in your solution, check that the project you want to debug is active. Right click it and select **Set as StartUp Project**.

This stumped me for a while since there are no obvious cues that the wrong website is being debugged.

Answer (score 1):

If you hover over your breakpoint and you see the 'No symbols have been loaded warning',

[image]

you may need to change your solution configuration from 'Release' to 'Debug'.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that worked for me was to uncheck "use the new exception helper". Let it catch an exception, stop the program, enable "use the new exception helper" then VS2019 magically started catching unhandled exceptions again.

I still do not have "user-unhandled" anywhere to be found in VS 2019 but at least it works now.

Answer (score 1):

I tried many suggestions here, but finally for me, switching `x86`/`x64` helped me solve the problem of VS debugger terminating without any error or exception.

[image: Screenshot]