# How to throw Exceptions on Wcf Service and catch it on client?

Tags: c#, wcf, xaml, exception

**Service Demo Code:**

```
  public class Login : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {
            if (new ProjectContext().Users.Count(x => x.Username == userName && x.Password == password) == 0)
            {
                throw new FaultException("Invalid login");
            }
        }  
    }
```

**Client Code Demo:**

```
internal bool LoginOnWcf(string address, string password) 
        {
            try
            {
                service.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
                service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = address;
                service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;
                user = service.GetUserById(address);
                return true;
            }
            catch (FaultException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

**Web.config Demo:**

```
<behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="defaultProfile">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" />
            </clientCertificate>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="App1" storeLocation="CurrentUser"
              storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="App1.App_Code.Authentication.Login, App_Code/Authentication"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

When i throw `FaultException`, the service crashs. 
I would like to be able to catch the `FaultException` on client and keep the service working.

I hope to have explained my problem well and provided the nescessary code.

Answer (score 5):

WCF uses Faults to throw errors across from the server to the client. You can use a `FaultException` to start and then create your own custom faults as needed.

So, in your example, you could simply do the following.

```
throw new FaultException("Invalid login")
```

This [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942778.aspx) provides a whole lot more detail on how to accomplish faults with WCF.

Comment: Could you please check my question update? Actually i am not  really being able to catch the `Exception` on client

Comment: 1. Are you sure that it is your throw of the fault that is causing the issue instead of some other exception?  You might want to consider wrapping the entire method in a try catch and throwing a fault from there. 2. You completely edited the question which makes my answer no longer valid. Your original question showed a lack of understanding faults, which my answer addressed.  If you have a new problem with Faults, you really should have asked a separate question.

Comment: I am really sorry. The problem was that the "break when this exception type is user-unhandled" option was activated.
You might want to improve your answer with this [picture](https://www.google.pt/search?q=break+when+this+exception+type+is+user-unhandled&espv=2&biw=1600&bih=794&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJ0YvludnRAhVIwxQKHRW1BYQQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=lB-bsjrDrJqY9M%3A)
and this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970642/visual-studio-not-breaking-on-user-unhandled-exceptions)