# C# connection.Open() exception

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to connect to my database on localhost but for some reason, it throws an exception, and I can't find out why and where.

```
private void Initialize()
    {
        server = "localhost";
        database = "dbname";
        uid = "uname";
        password = "pass";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
        database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

        connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }
```

This is my initialize function; my problem is with:

```
    private bool OpenConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            return true;
        }
             ...
```

When I debug the program, it stays on "connection.Open();" line for a while, then I see "Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll" on console. But it's not crashing, just skipping.

Comment: Is there an inner exception to that exception, and what are the exception message(s)?

Comment: after your try {} you chould have catch (Exception ex) { /* put break point here to view the contents of your exception (ex) */ }

Comment: @hatchet nothing else, just this one.

Comment: If you aren't stopping on the exception, that's a problem and I'd start there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970642/visual-studio-not-breaking-on-user-unhandled-exceptions  Once you can see what the exception actually is, you can give us more information.

Comment: @MBurnham i have it, just didn't post.

Comment: @osumatu if you want help figuring out what is causing the exeception, we will need to know more info about the exception. Or is your question simply "why is this not crashing?" (sorry if this seems blunt, my people-friendly-phrasing skills aren't the best yet)

Comment: @MBurnham the problem is openConnection() function is failing then returning false. i want to understand&solve why connection.Open() fails.

Comment: Please provide more information about the exception - additional information, inner exception, exception message, ...

Comment: @MetaColon guys i swear there is nothing else

Comment: @osumatu try this inside of your catch: Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

Comment: You have tagged this question with MySql however you try to open an Sql Server database. What is the right one?

Comment: @Steve i am trying to connect phpmyadmin, mysql. i wrote the codes by following a tutorial. is there something wrong about it?

Comment: @osumatu SqlConnection objects are used for Microsoft SQL Server, if you are doing my sql you will want to use OdbcConnection for a MySql server

Comment: No, there is a proper ADO.NET provider for MySql, no need to use the  ODBC driver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to open a connection with MySql, then you don't use the classes from `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace but with the classes from `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`

These classes are *MySqlConnection*, *MySqlCommand*, *MySqlDataReader* etc...
If you try to use the SqlConnection class you receive this error if the database to open is MySql because it can only work with the Sql Server, Sql Server Express or LocalDB database systems.

```
connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
```

Of course, to use the *MySql.Data.MySqlClient* namespace you need to download and install the [MySql NET Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) and then [add a reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx) into your project to the assembly MySql.Data.dll (and add the [*using MySql.Data.MySqlClient*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) to the top of each cs file that needs to use these classes)

Comment: will you marry me?

Comment: Please not that this requires the use of a third party namespace, MySql.Data is not provided in the .NET Framework by default. It is an ADO.NET driver provided by MySql

Comment: LOL ... didn't knew answering in SO can even get you marriage proposal ... Stevee you are so lucky ... :)

Comment: @Rahul it depends :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is not crashing because you are opening the connection inside of a try-catch block, so the program thinks you are handling the exception. If you want it to crash, get rid of the try-catch block. (This would be a bad user experience.)

Alternatively, after your try-catch, you could check   the connection is valid and then do something if it isn't.

```
if ((connection == null) || (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)) { 
    /* do something here to indicate to the user there was an issue.
}
```

Comment: i see, the problem is i can't open the connection so it returns null. but why is this happening i just can't understand this.

Comment: @osumatu you will need to provide us with the message from the exception (ex.message) for us to possibly answer that

Comment: In order to understand why it returns null, add a catch block as mentioned by @MBurnham and see what goes in there. It should tell you whether the credentials are incorrect or the user doesn't have the right kind of access.